# Can't receive $args[ ] to my custom widget

Tags: customization, widgets

I'm new to WordPress. I created my first ugly widget. It located in **wp-content/plugins/my-awesome-widget/widget_init.php** (no more files in this folder). And it's working.
I created a sidebar and registered it in **functions.php** in my theme folder:

```
function register_page_widgets()
{
    if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
        register_sidebar(
            array(
                'name' => 'Page sidebar',
                'id' => 'page_sidebar',
                'description' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'before_widget' => '<div class="page-sidebar">',
                'before_title' => '<div class="title"><span>',
                'after_title' => '</span></div>',
                'after_widget' => '</div>'
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_page_widgets' );
```

All widgets, that located in this sidebar, wrapped in elements, that I defined in array: *before_widget*, *before_title* etc. Besides my widget. In my code (in **widget_init.php**) I wrote:

```
print_r($args);
```

And I got the result:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Page sidebar
    [id] => page_sidebar
    [description] => 
    [class] => 
    [before_widget] =>     
    [after_widget] =>     
    [before_title] =>     
    [after_title] =>     
    [widget_id] => my_first_widget
    [widget_name] => My First Widget
)
```

Somehow *before_widget*, *after_widget*, *before_title* and *after_title* are empty. What's wrong?

My code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Own Recent Posts
Plugin URI: http://www.example.com/textwidget
Description: An example plugin to demonstrate widgets API in WordPress
Version: 0.1
Author: Author Name
Author URI: http://www.example.com
License: GPL2


*/
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
    register_widget( 'My_Own_Recent_Posts' );
});

class My_Own_Recent_Posts extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'My_Own_Recent_Posts', 
            'My First Widget', 
            array( 'description' => __( 'My First Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) 
        );
    }


    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array(); 
        $instance['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] );

        $instance['count_of_posts'] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['count_of_posts'] );

        $instance['words_to_display'] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['words_to_display'] );

        $instance['post_types'] =  $new_instance['post_types'];

        return $instance;
    }


    public function form( $instance ) { ?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat"
                   id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>"
                   type="text"
                   value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'count_of_posts' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Count of posts:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat"
                   id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'count_of_posts' ); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'count_of_posts' ); ?>"
                   type="number"
                   max="50"
                   min="1"
                   value="<?php echo $instance['count_of_posts']; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'words_to_display' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Words from post to display:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat"
                   id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'words_to_display' ); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'words_to_display' ); ?>"
                   type="number"
                   max="50"
                   min="1"
                   value="<?php echo $instance['words_to_display']; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_types' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Select post types:' ); ?><br></label>
            <?php
                $args = array('_builtin' => '', 'public' => true);
                $post_types = get_post_types($args, 'object');

                foreach($post_types as $post_type) : ?>
                <?php
                    $checked='';
                    if(@in_array($post_type->name, $instance['post_types'])) $checked='checked';
                ?>
                <input type="checkbox"
                       value="<?=$post_type->name?>"
                       name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'post_types' ).'[]'; ?>"
                       id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_types'); ?>"
                       <?=$checked?>><?=$post_type->labels->name?><br>
        <?  endforeach;

    }


    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        echo '<div class="page-sidebar"><div class="title"><span>'.$instance['title'].'</span></div>';

        function limit_words($string, $word_limit) {
            $words=explode(" ",$string);
            return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
        }

        function link_words($limited_string){
            $words = explode(' ', $limited_string);
            array_splice($words, 5, 0, "</a>");
            return implode(' ', $words);
        }

        if(!empty($instance)) :
            global $post;
            $posts = get_posts(
                array(
                    'numberposts'     => $instance['count_of_posts'],
                    'offset'          => 0,
                    'category'        => '',
                    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
                    'order'           => 'DESC',
                    'include'         => '',
                    'exclude'         => '',
                    'meta_key'        => '',
                    'meta_value'      => '',
                    'post_type'       => $instance['post_types'],
                    'post_mime_type'  => '',
                    'post_parent'     => '',
                    'post_status'     => 'publish'
                )
            );

            $shows=0;
            foreach($posts as $post){ setup_postdata($post);?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php echo link_words(limit_words(get_field('content'), $instance['words_to_display']))."...";
                if($shows != ($instance['count_of_posts']-1)) echo '<hr>';
                $shows++;
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;

        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your widget code please

Comment: Where are you puttint the `print_r`?

Comment: at the beginning of method _widget()_

Answer (score 0):

write like that in public function widget

```
echo $args['before_widget'] ;
echo $args['before_title'] ;
//your tile should here
echo echo $args['after_title'] ;
echo echo $args['after_widget'] ;
```

Comment: How does it answers OP question?